# How to find the iteration index in this loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iterator

I'm looking for a way to replace 'row' with the iteration number.

```
directions = 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right'
actions = 'idle', 'walk', 'fight', 'death'
frames = range(4)
duration = 0.2

animations = {
    action : {
        direction : (
            (duration, ('row', x)) for x in frames
        ) for direction in directions
    } for action in actions
}
```

So for example in 'idle' down will be 0, up 1, left 2, right 3, then in walk up 4, down 5 and so on.

Comment: have you tried using `range`? try `for i in range(len(directions))`?

Comment: Iteration number over `actions`, `directions` or `frames`? Or the product of all 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters of directions + actions

Comment: And did you mean for the `direction` values to be a generator expression?

Comment: @user11177: so the same iteration number for all frames?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's correct.

Comment: use `enumerate` to have the index and the element of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` to calculate your iterations:

```
animations = {
    action : {
        direction : (
            (duration, (i * len(directions) + j, x)) for x in frames
        ) for j, direction in enumerate(directions)
    } for i, action in enumerate(actions)
}
```

This produces:

```
>>> pprint({action: {direction: [(duration, (i * len(directions) + j, x)) for x in frames] for j, direction in enumerate(directions) } for i, action in enumerate(actions)})
{'death': {'down': [(0.2, (12, 0)),
                    (0.2, (12, 1)),
                    (0.2, (12, 2)),
                    (0.2, (12, 3))],
           'left': [(0.2, (14, 0)),
                    (0.2, (14, 1)),
                    (0.2, (14, 2)),
                    (0.2, (14, 3))],
           'right': [(0.2, (15, 0)),
                     (0.2, (15, 1)),
                     (0.2, (15, 2)),
                     (0.2, (15, 3))],
           'up': [(0.2, (13, 0)),
                  (0.2, (13, 1)),
                  (0.2, (13, 2)),
                  (0.2, (13, 3))]},
 'fight': {'down': [(0.2, (8, 0)),
                    (0.2, (8, 1)),
                    (0.2, (8, 2)),
                    (0.2, (8, 3))],
           'left': [(0.2, (10, 0)),
                    (0.2, (10, 1)),
                    (0.2, (10, 2)),
                    (0.2, (10, 3))],
           'right': [(0.2, (11, 0)),
                     (0.2, (11, 1)),
                     (0.2, (11, 2)),
                     (0.2, (11, 3))],
           'up': [(0.2, (9, 0)), (0.2, (9, 1)), (0.2, (9, 2)), (0.2, (9, 3))]},
 'idle': {'down': [(0.2, (0, 0)),
                   (0.2, (0, 1)),
                   (0.2, (0, 2)),
                   (0.2, (0, 3))],
          'left': [(0.2, (2, 0)),
                   (0.2, (2, 1)),
                   (0.2, (2, 2)),
                   (0.2, (2, 3))],
          'right': [(0.2, (3, 0)),
                    (0.2, (3, 1)),
                    (0.2, (3, 2)),
                    (0.2, (3, 3))],
          'up': [(0.2, (1, 0)), (0.2, (1, 1)), (0.2, (1, 2)), (0.2, (1, 3))]},
 'walk': {'down': [(0.2, (4, 0)),
                   (0.2, (4, 1)),
                   (0.2, (4, 2)),
                   (0.2, (4, 3))],
          'left': [(0.2, (6, 0)),
                   (0.2, (6, 1)),
                   (0.2, (6, 2)),
                   (0.2, (6, 3))],
          'right': [(0.2, (7, 0)),
                    (0.2, (7, 1)),
                    (0.2, (7, 2)),
                    (0.2, (7, 3))],
          'up': [(0.2, (5, 0)), (0.2, (5, 1)), (0.2, (5, 2)), (0.2, (5, 3))]}}
```

Alternatively, use a [`itertools.count()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) with [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next); this is helpful if your inner loop uses a variable number of elements based on the outer loop:

```
from itertools import count

iter_count = count()

animations = {
    action : {
        direction : (
            (duration, (count, x)) for c in (next(iter_count),) for x in frames
        ) for direction in directions
    } for action in actions
}
```

Comment: Ok this solved my question, helped me see that it's not necessary to include duration in the inner loop, as well as made me question the sanity of using this manner of dictionary comprehension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply suggest making a counter, and building your structures using `for` loops:

```
animations = {}
row = 0

for action in actions:
    d = {}
    for direction in directions:
        rows = []
        for x in frames:
            rows.append((duration, (row, x))
            row += 1
        d[direction] = rows
    animations[action] = d
```